# How Do I store my POST While Loop

Tags: php, variables, post, while-loop

Let me know if you want more details but:

I have an different number of inserts I need to make based on a POST form data that I created in a loop.
If I were to write it all out it would look like this:

```
$Scout1=$_POST['ScoutID1'];

$Scout2=$_POST['ScoutID2'];
```

and it keeps going until it reaches "x" I do have that number stored as
`$ScoutCount`
(so if the above code would post all the variables I brought over `{$ScoutCount=2}`

I can't find a way to do:

```
while (X>0){
$ScoutX=$_POST['ScoutIDX'];
X--;
}
```

how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

But rather, I would recommend storing the data in an array, as opposed to individual variables. Then in a for loop, it could look like:

```
$scouts = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
{
  $scouts[$i] = $_POST['ScoutID' . $i];
}
```

or something.

Comment: May need to make that `for` be `for ($i = 1; $i <= $ScoutCount; $i++)`

Comment: I used: ($i = 1; $i <= $ScoutCount; $i++)

Answer (score 1):

instead of having form fields called ScoutID1, ScoutID2 wtc name them

```
name="ScoutID[]"
```

then you will have a nice array with work with

Answer (score 0):

```
//put scoutIDs into Array
$scouts = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= $ScoutCount; $i++)
{
  $scouts[$i] = $_POST['ScoutID' . $i];
}
```

Thanks - that may have seemed easy but I wasted a day trying to figure it out.  thanks from the newbie to Php....